# Can't bind to 'highlight' since it isn't a known property of 'code'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to use [ngx-highlightjs](https://github.com/MurhafSousli/ngx-highlightjs) and I have the following code in the module file. I have multiple modules and so I am importing the HighlightModule, in the module in which the highlighting functionality is needed. So the following code is not in App Module.

```
import { HighlightModule, HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS, HighlightOptions} from 'ngx-highlightjs';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EnvironmentComponent,
    RepositoryComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    HighlightModule
  ],
  providers: [
    EnvironmentService,
    AuthService,
    {
      provide: HIGHLIGHT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: {
        coreLibraryLoader: () => import('highlight.js/lib/core'),
        lineNumbersLoader: () => import('highlightjs-line-numbers.js'),
        languages: {
          typescript: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/typescript'),
          css: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/css'),
          xml: () => import('highlight.js/lib/languages/xml')
        }
      }
    }
  ],
})
```

and in the component template, I have the code like this :

```
<pre><code [highlight]="fileData" (highlighted)="onHighlight($event)"></code></pre>
```

Now I am getting the following error and the output is not showing :

`Can't bind to 'highlight' since it isn't a known property of 'code'`

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal reproducible example on [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com)? Also note that some inputs could require a directive selector to be used

Comment: Show closest NgModule which contains your component template. Its likely missing an import of HighlightModule.

Comment: It is as mentioned in the above code. I have double checked and it contains the import. I need to do the import in both `AppModule` and the module I have the template in ?

Comment: did you fix the problem ? @HappyCoder

Comment: @luckystones unfortuntaely no

Comment: @pixelbits I have tried to import as you mentioned. But it is still showing the same error.

Comment: Actually this issue is in a modal box that I am using. In ordinary pages, it is working fine

Comment: I was struggling with same problem for whole day. And fixed the issue by installing issue highlightjs and adding into angular.json.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is related to that angular doesn't see native javascript library which is highlight.js in this case. Because highlight attribute is directive defined by highlight.js

I also had same problem. And fixed the issue by following these steps.

1- I installed highlight.js manually in project directory.

```
npm install highlight.js
```

2- added following lines to scripts and styles parts in angular.json file.

```
    "styles":[ 
     "./node_modules/highlight.js/styles/default.css"
     ],
    "scripts": [
     "./node_modules/highlight.js/lib/highlight.js"
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also think of adding the HighlightModule in your component's module

myCompo.module.ts :

```
import { HighlightModule } from 'ngx-highlightjs';    
imports: [
    ....
    HighlightModule,
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).